# I can not edit a field in my database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem I can not edit  the field birthdate in my database .I need help please.
this is the code.employees.php

```
    $Nom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nom"]);
    $Id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);
    $Prenom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["prenom"]);
    $BirthDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["birthdate"]);
    $rs = mysql_query(" UPDATE users SET nom = '" .$Nom ."', prenom = '" .$Prenom ."', birtdate = '" .$BirthDate."' WHERE id = " .$Id) or die(mysql_error());
    echo json_encode($rs);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Maybe you forgot a double quote? `WHERE id = " .$Id.'"')` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 2):

Your query is referencing a field named `birtdate`, which according to your question and the spelling in the rest of your code should be `birthdate`

```
$rs = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET nom = '" .$Nom ."', prenom = '" .$Prenom ."', birthdate = '" .$BirthDate."' WHERE id = " .$Id) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it should be a comment if u are guessing the mistake

Comment: @dianuj Everything seems correct, he says "can not edit the field ***birthdate***" with the value from the `$_POST["birthdate"]` yet his SQL says `birtdate =`

Comment: good catch +1 for you

Comment: i don't have error this is my index.html `